# how to get interface traffic snmp information for routers ( cisco, zte, huawei ...)?

Tags: networking, cisco, router, snmp, mib

I have cisco, zte, huawei routers..How can i get the traffic information of every interfaces of these routers. I donot have mib file of zte and huawei. So, i want a generic mib file which can monitor every interfaces of these routers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Nick R already mentioned, you need [IF-MIB](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&step=2&mibName=IF-MIB)... details matter though.

You can correlate all OIDs to an interface name below by snmp walking `ifName`: `1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1`.

**High Speed interfaces**

For high-speed interfaces (100Mbps or above) you should use 64-bit counters if the device supports them:

- `ifHCInOctets`: `1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6` (*64-bit Octets in counter*)
- `ifHCOutOctets`: `1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10` (*64-bit Octets out counter*)
- `ifHCInUcastPkts`:    `1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.7` (*64-bit Packets in counter*)
- `ifHCOutUcastPkts`:   `1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.11` (*64-bit Packets out counter*)
- `ifHighSpeed`: `1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.15` (*An estimate of the interface's current bandwidth in units of 1Mbps*)

**Low Speed interfaces**

Lower speed interfaces can get by with 32-bit counters.  If you use 32-bit counters on high-speed interfaces, they can wrap quickly; a 10 Mbps stream of back-to-back, full-size packets causes `ifInOctets` to wrap in just over 57 minutes. At 100 Mbps, the minimum wrap time is 5.7 minutes, and at 1 Gbps, the minimum is 34 seconds <sup>Note 1</sup>

- `ifInOctets`: `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10` (*32-bit Octets in counter*)
- `ifOutOctets`: `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16` (*32-bit Octets out counter*)
- `ifInUcastPkts`: `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.11` (*32-bit Packets in counter*)
- `ifOutUcastPkts`: `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.17` (*32-bit Packets out counter*)
- `ifSpeed`: `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5` (*Currently negotiated speed of the interface - Max: 4.294 Gbps*)

---

Note 1: Quoted from [Cisco's SNMP FAQ](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_q_and_a_item09186a00800b69ac.shtml)

Comment: The link refers to the original IF-MIB, without the ifXTable extensions.  The full description can be found at [rfc2863](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2863).  Cisco has a plain text version of the extended [IF-MIB](ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/v2/IF-MIB.my).

Answer (score 3):

[IF-MIB](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/mibs/IF-MIB.txt) should be what you are looking for. The OID you want is ifInOctets and ifOutOctets.

Answer (score 3):

[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) is the most strait forward way to go.

Download an install it, it will work with a lot of routers and switches straight out of the box. Also, [Observium](http://www.observium.org/wiki/Main_Page) is even easier to get going but less customisable than Cacti; although it does also work with most switches and routers strait out of the box.

**Update**: Forgot to say these include the MIBs!

Comment: +1 for observium, it's great if you're a service provider